# Is there a theme with a short or transparent title bar?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, transparency, window-management, tabs

Is there any theme, under *any* ubuntu desktop or window manager,
that has the feature illustrated in the image below, where the title bar doesn't occupy the whole width, but is instead as short as the title? (or is transparent away from the title)?

I run Ubuntu 22.04.2. I use xubuntu-desktop but that's not a given.  I can switch to any desktop supported by Ubuntu.

All the themes I see in /usr/share/themes differ only in esthetic details.  For years I used a theme, called B5, that has a key advantage, which I'll describe but is easier to see in the attached screenshot: the title bar of windows doesn't take up the whole width of the window. It's just as wide as the title, and I keep my titles short, so I can find  windows quickly and click on them even when they overlap, so long as the title bars don't overlap. It functions just like tabs.

B5 disappeared from the distribution many years ago and I've kept using it by migrating the /usr/share/themes/B5 to each new distribution and each new computer.  But the newest migration broke it.  Is there *any* theme with this property, or any other way to achieve a similar effect?[image: screenshot showing tablike arrangement of windows under B5 theme]

Comment: Hi guiverc - In the original question I said I'd accept an answer for any window manager -- I mean for any window manager + desktop combination.  I've updated the question, hopefully it's clear now.  Bottom line: the short title bar (or mostly transparent title bar) issue is more important for me than the desktop environment.  Thanks.